# Why this structure-preserving "fmap" cannot be acepted in this Functor's class instance?

Tags: haskell, functor, category-abstractions

The below defined function **mapRightR** change only the map's set contents, not the keys and produce a valid Relation type.

Is it really impossible use this high-level function to define the Functor Relation instance, or is my implementation wrong.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

import Data.Map as M
import Data.Set as S

data Relation a b where
    R :: (Ord a, Ord b) => Map a (Set b) -> Relation a b

instance Functor Relation where
    fmap f r = mapRightR f r

mapRightR :: Ord b1 => (b2 -> b1) -> Relation a b2 -> Relation a b1
mapRightR f (R r) = R $ M.map (S.map f) r
```

Thanks, **chepner**.

I tried another definition of Relation, using *List* instead of Set and it work!

```
data Relation a b where
    R :: (Ord a) => Map a [b] -> Relation a b

instance Functor (Relation a) where
    fmap f r = mapRightR f r

mapRightR :: (b2 -> b1) -> Relation a b2 -> Relation a b1
mapRightR f (R r) = R $ M.map (L.map f) r
```

Comment: It is impossible because `Set` is not a `Functor`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`mapRightR` is constrained, it will not work for *any* type `b` as `fmap` requires:

```
-- Specialized for f ~ Relation c
fmap ::               (a -> b) -> Relation c a -> Relation c b
```

but

```
mapRightR :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> Relation c a -> Relation c b
```

---

In more categorical terms, `Relation c` is not an endofunctor that maps **Hask** to **Hask** (which is what the `Functor` typeclass represents), but rather a functor that maps a subcategory of **Hask** consisting only of types with `Ord` instances to **Hask**. (I think I characterized this correctly; corrections welcome.)